# LabelOnlyMarkers in R Leaflet with specific colors

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I want to build a `leaflet` map with `CircleMarkers` and `LabelOnlyMarkers` atop the circles. Labels and circles should have colors specified in a `data.frame` column.

The following does what I want, except for the coloring of the `LabelOnlyMarkers.` How can I change the `labelOptions` to plot the labels in the correct colors?

Or is there maybe an even simpler solution?

---

Here is my attempt:

*The part `style = list("color" = data$col)))` does not define the colors dynamically but seems to be ignored..*

```
library(leaflet)

data <- data.frame(lat = c(47, 48, 47), 
                   lng = c(8, 9, 10),
                   label = c("bli", "bla", "blo"),
                   col = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

leaflet()  %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.CH, group = "OSM") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = data$lng, 
                   lat = data$lat, 
                   fillColor = data$col, 
                   radius = 5, opacity = 0, fillOpacity = 1) %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(lng = data$lng, 
                      lat = data$lat, 
                      label = data$label,
                      labelOptions = labelOptions(
                        noHide = T, direction = 'top', 
                        textOnly = T, textsize = "20px", 
                        style = list("color" = data$col)))
```

---

This produces:

[image]

... which is - apart from the black `LabelOnlyMarkers` - exactly what I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58104565/vary-label-color-in-r-leaflet):

```r
# apply label w/ color as HTML
data <- data |>
    dplyr::mutate(
        lab_html = purrr::map(
            glue::glue(
                "<span style='color:{data$col}'>{as.character(data$label)}<span>"
            ),
            htmltools::HTML
        )
    )

# map
leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.CH, group = "OSM") %>%
    addCircleMarkers(
        lng = data$lng,
        lat = data$lat,
        fillColor = data$col,
        radius = 5, opacity = 0, fillOpacity = 1
    ) %>%
    addLabelOnlyMarkers(
        lng = data$lng,
        lat = data$lat,
        label = data$lab_html,
        labelOptions = labelOptions(
            noHide = TRUE, direction = "top",
            textOnly = TRUE, textsize = "20px"
        )
    )
```

Yields:

[image: map]

Hope that helps!